# Batch - Ghost File Passing 'If Not Exist' Check

Tags: batch-file, file-exists, not-exists

### My Code

I have some straight forward code below that:

1. Checks if a file exists in my directory
2. Runs a for loop to get the first filename
3. Does stuff based on filename
4. Deletes the file
5. Checks if any other files exist in directory (if yes, repeat, if not, move on)

   ```
   :MYLOOP
   IF NOT EXIST "%mypath%\*.*" GOTO nofile
   FOR %%F IN ("%mypath%\*.*") DO (
       set filenameWithExt=%%~nxF
       set filename=%%~nF
       set filepath=%%~pF
       )
   do other filename specific tasks

   del "%mypath%\%filenameWithExt%"

   IF NOT EXIST "%mypath%\*.*" GOTO nofile

   GOTO MYLOOP

   :nofile
   ```

### My Issue

I've used this code repeatedly and its worked like a charm, but on my most recent use it looks like its finding a 'ghost' file. When there are **no FILES** (there is a single archive FOLDER) in the directory, the `if not exist` check from step 1 above somehow is still passing. As a result, the `set` code in the for loop results in:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

And it then appears as though it tries to delete my directory, saying:

> \\mypath*, Are you sure (Y/N)?

I then have to manually terminate an otherwise automated batch.

### My Question

Why is it passing the `if not exist` check, rather than skipping to :nofile?

How can I account for this 'ghost' file (or if it is detecting the archive folder -- how else can I ignore it)?

Comment: So, do you want to check if there's any file in `%mypath%` before proceed?

Comment: I would suggest you, if you are going to work with the files inside `%mypath%`, to do it by iterating over the output of `dir /b "%mypath%\*.*"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if exist` test looks for *anything* in the directory.

I'd restructure you code:

```dos
:MYLOOP
set "found1="
FOR %%F IN ("%mypath%\*.*") DO (
    set filenameWithExt=%%~nxF
    set filename=%%~nF
    set filepath=%%~pF
    set "found1=Y"
    )
if not defined found1 goto nofile

do other filename specific tasks

del "%mypath%\%filenameWithExt%"
GOTO MYLOOP

:nofile
```

If the `for` finds no files, `found1` will remain undefined so we go to the `:nofile` label, else we have a file to process. Having deleted the file, just go back to the beginning, clear the flag and repeat...

Comment: haven't implemented it yet, but logic looks perfectly sound to me -- obviously deep at this point that I couldn't see the forest through the trees. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Windows kernel and therefore also Windows command interpreter interprets the wildcard pattern `*.*` like `*` which means any file or folder. On using wildcard pattern `*.*` it does not mean there must be a file (or folder) with a dot in name.

For that reason using the condition `IF NOT EXIST "%mypath%\*.*"` is the same as using `IF NOT EXIST "%mypath%\*"`.

`IF EXIST "%mypath%\*"` is often used in batch files to verify that `%mypath%` specifies a folder and not a file because this condition checks if there is a folder `%mypath%`. The condition is **true** if that folder exists, independent on number of files and folders in that folder.

So the condition at top of your batch file does not check if there is not at least 1 file in folder `%mypath%`, it checks if this folder does not exist at all.

You could use the following batch code which avoids the usage of delayed expansion by using a subroutine.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /ON "%mypath%\*" 2^>nul') do call :ProcessFile "%mypath%\%%I"
goto :EOF

:ProcessFile
set "FilenNmeWithExt=%~nx1"
set "FileName=%~n1"
set "FilePath=%~p1"
rem do other filename specific tasks
del "%~1"
goto :EOF
```

The command **FOR** executes the command line

```
dir /A-D /B /ON "%mypath%\*" 2>nul
```

in a separate command process in background and captures the output of **DIR** written to handle **STDOUT**.

**DIR** would output an error message to handle **STDERR** if the directory does not exist at all or does not contain any file. This error message is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** using `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted first by Windows command interpreter as literal character on parsing the entire **FOR** command line as otherwise a syntax error would be the result.

Option `/A-D` means that **DIR** should output all directory entries NOT having directory attribute set, i.e. just files, not folders. `/B` changes output of **DIR** to bare format which means only the file names without any additional data. `/ON` results in ordering the list by file name before **DIR** outputs the entire list. This option would not be really necessary here.

**FOR** processes now the captured output of **DIR**. So it does not matter that files from that directory are deleted while **FOR** is running. **FOR** processes the initial list as output by **DIR**.

For each file name output by **DIR** the subroutine `ProcessFile` is executed which is like calling another batch file with that name. Passed to the subroutine is the file name with its path. **DIR** outputs just the file name without path on not using additionally `/S` to get a list of all file names in specified directory and all its subdirectories.

The command `goto :EOF` after the **FOR** loop is required to avoid a fall through to the subroutine once all file names output by **DIR** have been processed.

The command `goto :EOF` after the subroutine would not be required if the line above is the last line of the batch file. But it is in general good practice to end a subroutine always with `goto :EOF` in case of ever adding more command lines like another subroutine below. For Windows command interpreter it does not matter where the subroutine starting with its label is located in the file.

Comment: wow! Thank you for the detailed response @mofi! I've already accepted Magoo's answer, but I wanted to quickly respond with my thanks. There are definitely a few tid-bits that I'll keep in mind for the future.